# KOMA script's unnumbered chapters incorrectly displayed by enotez

Tags: koma-script, endnotes, enotez

When KOMA script's `addchap` is used for the first and last chapters (i.e. Introduction and Conclusion, respectively), the former appears in the `enotez` package's endnotes as Chapter 0 and the latter as a repeat of the previous chapter. How can I fix this?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,notetype=endonly,autocite=footnote,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{
    list-heading=\addchap{#1},
    split=chapter,
    reset=true,
}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\addchap{Introduction}
\lipsum[1] \autocite{aksin}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-3] \autocite{bertram}

\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum[1-3] \autocite{doody}

\addchap{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1] \autocite{kullback}

\backmatter
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution for the specific problem (not a general solution for more complex cases, though…):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,notetype=endonly,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{
  list-heading=\addchap{#1},
  split=chapter,
  reset=true
}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_enotez_last_splittitle_tl
\AtEveryListSplit{
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__enotez_last_split_id_tl
    { \tl_set:Nn \EnotezCurrentSplitTitle {Notes~ from~ the~ Introduction} }
    {
      \tl_if_eq:NNT \l_enotez_last_splittitle_tl \EnotezCurrentSplitTitle
        { \tl_set:Nn \EnotezCurrentSplitTitle {Notes~ from~ the~ Conclusion} }
    }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_enotez_last_splittitle_tl \EnotezCurrentSplitTitle
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\addchap{Introduction}
\lipsum[1] \autocite{aksin}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-3] \autocite{bertram}

\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum[1-3] \autocite{doody}

\addchap{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1] \autocite{kullback}

\backmatter
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]