# How do I get enotez to give me the headings I want?

Tags: chapters, endnotes, enotez

I'm trying to create endnotes separated by chapter, and I'm having trouble. [This comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628520/enotez-uses-wrong-headings-for-numbered-unnumbered-chapters#comment1567565_628520) makes me think that what I'm trying to do may not be possible using this package; if that's the case then I'll need to find some other solution. But if it *is* possible, how can I make it happen?

(What I'm looking for is headings that just have the chapter titles: Epistola Præfatoria, Liber Primus, Liber Alter. If that's not possible, then even just chapter numbers would be good, but I can't get those to happen either; when I add `<rev>` all I get is "Chapter 0" over and over again.)

Here's an MWE, though it's clearly wrong.

```
\documentclass[openany]{octavo}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-name={Fontes et Adnotationes},split=chapter,split-title={<name>}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Epistola Præfatoria}

Here is a line from the preface\endnote[\relax]{Here is an endnote for that line.}.

\chapter{Liber Primus}

Here is a line from chapter one\endnote[\relax]{Here is an endnote for that line.}.

\chapter{Liber Alter}

Here is a line from chapter two\endnote[\relax]{Here is an endnote for that line.}.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack based on `octavo`'s feature of not numbering chapters.

```
\documentclass[openany]{octavo}
\usepackage{enotez}

\setenotez{
  list-name={Fontes et Adnotationes},
  split=chapter,
  split-title=<ref>,
}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\stepcounter{chapter}\def\thechapter{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Epistola Præfatoria}

Here is a line from the preface\endnote[\relax]{Here is an endnote for that line.}.

\chapter{Liber Primus}

Here is a line from chapter one\endnote[\relax]{Here is an endnote for that line.}.

\chapter{Liber Alter}

Here is a line from chapter two\endnote[\relax]{Here is an endnote for that line.}.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `<ref>` uses the expansion of `\thechapter`. Therefore we can abuse `\thechapter` to set it to the chapter's title.

[image]